# Is the countable direct product and direct sums of short exact sequence still short exact sequence in additive category?

Tags: category-theory

Let $$0\longrightarrow L^{(i)}\longrightarrow M^{(i)}\longrightarrow N^{(i)}\longrightarrow 0$$ be a short exact sequence of abelian groups for every index $i$. Clearly if I take finite direct products, then $$0\longrightarrow \prod_iL^{(i)}\longrightarrow\prod_i M^{(i)}\longrightarrow\prod_iN^{(i)}\longrightarrow 0$$ is a short exact sequence. But how about countable direct product and countable direct sums.And I know in    the abelian category,we need AB,AB4 and their dual，so that the infinity direct product and sums of short exact sequences is still short exact sequence. But how about countable direct product and sums  of short exact sequence?

Answer (score 2):

It is an elementary straight forward calculcation (no ideas are necessary) that exact sequences of abelian groups are stable under arbitrary products (and coproducts as well). Countability is not relevant. This also means that $\mathbf{Ab}$ satisfies AB5 and AB5* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) for the definition). Notice that the category of abelian sheaves on a topological space still satisfies AB5, but not necessarily AB5*, in fact even AB4* does not need to be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, exact sequences of modules are stable under arbitrary product. But how about in arbitrary additive category?

Comment: My answer gives a class of counterexamples.

Comment: But  AB4* is for any  infinity  index set , not only for countable  infinity.

Comment: Small correction:  although exact sequences in $\mathbf{Ab}$ are stable under all products and coproducts (i.e. $\mathbf{Ab}$ satisfies AB4 and AB4*), they are not stable under filtered limits, so $\mathbf{Ab}$ does not satisfy AB5*.  Example:  take the limit of $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z \to 0$.  In fact, no nonzero abelian category satisfies both AB5 and AB5*; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25679/abelian-categories-axioms-ab5-and-ab5-and-incompatibility.