# Is taking (co)limits exact in an Abelian category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a complete and cocomplete Abelian category.

Let $J$ a small category, and let $F_1 \xrightarrow{r} F_2 \xrightarrow{s} F_3$ be a sequence of diagrams/functors $F_i : J\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ with $r,s$ natural transformations.

Suppose for each object $j\in \mathrm{Obj}(J)$ the sequence
$0\rightarrow F_1(j) \xrightarrow {r_j} F_2(j) \xrightarrow {s_j} F_3(j)\rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence in $\mathcal{A}$.

If we take the limits (or colimits) $M_i = \mathrm{(co)lim}F_i$ we get an induced sequence $0 \rightarrow M_1 \xrightarrow {\rho} M_2 \xrightarrow{\sigma} M_3 \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

In general is the sequence of $M_i$'s necessarily exact?

Comment: What is the limit taken over and what is the limit taken of?

Comment: @MathematicalEmergency If you mean that I should clarify the meaning of the limit, I've now edited the post to clarify, $M_i = \mathrm{(co)lim}F_i$. If you're asking what situation I'm considering: I'm interested in the case where the F's are actually a J-shaped long exact sequence (i.e. gives a long exact sequence for each $j\in J$), e.g. a projective or injective resolution of some object in $\mathcal{A}$. I'd like to know whether taking the (co)limit preserves the exactness of the long sequence.

Comment: Sounds like you need a sort of Mittag-Leffler condition but to generalize it to something other than the linearly ordered set of natural numbers.

Comment: If you restrict to *filtered* limits and colimits, these conditions are Grothendieck's [AB5 and AB5* axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category#Grothendieck's_axioms), which any given abelian category may or may not satisfy.  For example, the category of $R$-modules always satisfies AB5 (see Proposition 4 in Geoff's second link), but never AB5* unless $R = 0$ in view of [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25679/abelian-categories-axioms-ab5-and-ab5-and-incompatibility).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In complete generality you only preserve one side of the short exact sequence. Taking colimits is a right exact operation while taking limits is a left exact operation and in general neither is two-sided exact.  [For a counter-example to two-sided exactness, see, for instance, Example 10.8.9 of the Stacks Project.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07N7) [For a different counter-example, try the example on the bottom of page 5 of this reference as well.](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Kiersz.pdf)

By the way, a proof of the fact that taking colimits is always right exact follows from the fact that colimits commute with other colimits and cokernels are colimits in Abelian categories; the statment about limits follows dually.